# Log4j: WARN while running server log

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic

Could anyone help me out to fix this issue,

We are migrating Weblogic 11g(10.3.2) to (10.3.6), we have two managed servers in cluster.

If we start a managed server and look at the log for servers status, it prints,

"log4j:WARN Failure in post-close rollover action" for many times.

Why this line is getting printed in server log file?? what could be the route cause??

How do you advise me to fix this issue?

Comment: Is there anything in the application logs? Anyway it looks like some problem with the state of the server. Try shut it all down, clear all caches(temp, stage, ldap etc) and then redeploy

Comment: Thanks for immediate response.. I don't see anything in the application logs. Only after starting the server and checking the Server log it prints this line "log4j:WARN Failure in post-close rollover action" for many times.

Comment: Yes we have even tried to shutdown and restart the servers. Do we face this issue cos of log4j.xml config? Is there is any possibility ?

Comment: Does your oracle(or user you're running the wls with) user have rights to the directory, where you are logging? Is there enough space on the disk? You could try switching to consoleappender and watch the output of the server.

Comment: Yes, the user has rights to the directory. shall i show you the log4j.xml we use ?

Comment: <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS},&lt;%X{username}&gt;] %5p (%C{1}:%M) - %m%n" />
</layout>
</appender>

Comment: <appender name="ABAT_GENERAL" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
   <param name="ActiveFileName" value="${domain.home}/logs/103_${weblogic.Name}/abat-general.log" />
   <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${domain.home}/logs/103_${weblogic.Name}/archives/abat-general.log.%i" />
   <param name="MaxIndex" value="8" />
  </rollingPolicy>

Comment: <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
   <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000000" />
  </triggeringPolicy>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS},&lt;%X{username}&gt;] %5p (%C{1}:%M) - %m%n" />
  </layout>

Comment: With this log4j.xml content, could you find out any flaw which is creating this issue ??

Comment: There could be a few reasons I guess. Does the archive directory exist? Aren't there some strange characters on the path? Like spaces, semicolons etc. There are also some other questions regarding this on stackoverflow, but without accepted answer.

Comment: Wow.. That really helped me to fix this issue.. That archive directory was missing.. I created and checked the logged.. Issue got resolved.. Thanks a lot NeplantnyUdaj.. I've been breaking my head for a month..

Comment: it could be that you are in an application server

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj how do I know what is causing the issue? If the exception is null then only this message gets logged.